# Google IO Twitter Livefeed from a fresh install

Tags: android, twitter, io

I just dowloaded the Google IO Source code from here: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/ in order to understand the great UI of this app.

I also wanted to grab the code of the Twitter LiveFeed, but when compiling freshly downloaded code, I get a crazy UI:

[image]

I don't understand what's wrong as I didn't changed one line of the code!

Does this issue happens on other people devices?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself in case other people also searching for the answer:

http://twitter.com/#!/romannurik/statuses/69818965840506880

> yes we used some custom Google
>   Realtime Search tweaks that I
>   explicitly removed from open source.

So that seem impossible for now... Or we will have to look for other alternatives

Comment: Well, It's not impossible. They did do it in their app. My guess is they did some clever javascript-thing to remove the unwanted elements. I might try that myself in the coming week, and I'll get back to you if I do and get it working! Or you could try it yourself, and get back to me.

Comment: If you can do something, that would be amazing for the community and all developers. That could create a kind of standart for a lot of applications! Unfortunately, I have no knowledge at all in Javascript or web things, so I cannot help at all.